# hotel reservation query for booking date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to get result of a queries into array and the results should compare each one and merge into one array.

i have 3 queries, i don't know what's is wrong in my coding, my best is not enough so guys please help me especially the experts for sql and php.

here's my code:

```
        <?php
        $a = $p['id'];
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM prereservation where '$arrival' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);  

        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM prereservation where '$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);

        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM prereservation where arrival > '$arrival' and departure < '$departure' and room_id ='$a' and status = 'active'");
        $rows3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);

        $sample = array_unique(array_merge($rows1, $rows2, $rows3));             
        ?>
```

and the display is like this:

```
        <select id="select" name="qty[]" style=" width:50px;" onchange="checkall()">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <? $counter = 1; ?>
        <? while ($counter <= ($p['qty']) - $????????) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
        <? $counter++;
        }?>
        </select>
```

all i want for example output is like this:

```
$rows1 = array(id= 48, 55, 51, 53)
$rows2 = array(id= 48, 49, 51, 52)
$rows3 = array(id= 48, 49, 50, 51)
$sample = array_unique(array_merge($rows1, $rows2, $rows3))
```

so the output of sample is like this:

```
$sample = array(id= 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53)
```

then in table prereservation the columns are: '**id**', '**arrival**', '**departure**', '**room_id**', '**qty**' and '**status**'.

in my table prereservation each **id** has ***different*** **qty**, so i want **sum** of **qty** of each **id**'s for sample like this:

```
    id    |   qty
    48    |    2
    49    |    1
    50    |    1
    51    |    3   
    52    |    1
    53    |    3  


$total = sum(qty); which is 11
```

can you guys help me how to create a query to get the ***sum*** of those ***qty*** by each ***id***'s? also please check the first **3** queries because i know i have an **error** for each query. to get the **array_merge** and **array_unique**.
thank you very much guys.

```
            <select id="select" name="qty[]" style=" width:50px;" onchange="checkall()">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <? $counter = 1; ?>
            <? while ($counter <= ($p['qty']) - $total) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $counter ?>"><?php echo $counter ?></option>
            <? $counter++;
            }?>
            </select>
```

here my database:

```
table rooms
id |  type   |  qty
---|---------|-----
11 | single  |  50
12 | double  |  50
13 | deluxe  |  20

table preservation
id |   arrival   |  departure  | room_id | qty | status
---|-------------|-------------|---------|-----|-------
48 | 05/11/2012  | 11/11/2012  |    11   |  2  | active 
49 | 06/11/2012  | 11/11/2012  |    11   |  1  | active 
50 | 06/11/2012  | 08/11/2012  |    11   |  1  | active 
51 | 05/11/2012  | 07/11/2012  |    11   |  3  | active 
52 | 06/11/2012  | 09/11/2012  |    11   |  1  | active 
53 | 07/11/2012  | 07/11/2012  |    11   |  3  | active
```

so in my display i have an select tag from **table rooms(id=11)** and the option is **qty** and **deducted** by **total sum** of **qty** from table **preservation(room_id=11)**

Comment: Why not make one SQL query and join the where clauses with an OR?

Answer (score 0):

Use one SQL statement for your selection,

```
"SELECT id, SUM(qty) FROM prereservation GROUP BY qty WHERE ( ( '$arrival' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' ) OR ( '$departure' BETWEEN arrival and departure and room_id ='$a' ) OR ( arrival > '$arrival' and departure < '$departure' and room_id ='$a' ) ) AND status = 'active'";
```

Edit:

ok what about something like this?

```
SELECT *, (SELECT SUM(preservation.qty) as sum FROM preservation WHERE rooms.id = preservation.room_id GROUP BY preservation.room_id ) as qty_reserved, rooms.qty - (SELECT SUM(preservation.qty) as sum FROM preservation WHERE rooms.id = preservation.room_id GROUP BY preservation.room_id ) as qty_available  FROM rooms;
```

It's much more efficient going to the database once, getting all the information you need and reusing that throughout your application.  You shouldn't need any logic in your php if just displaying these variables.

Comment: i already used this kind of query but the problem is each id that is in range of those 3 operators the sum is of each id also doubled, tripled or higher, because sum of it will be deducted from my other table called rooms where columns have room_id and qty.

Comment: i think its much better to get id's of those 3 queries and use  array_merge and array_unique and get the sum of qty of the result id's.

Comment: sorry im lost after your explaination, maybe an example of the tables will help?  and the result you would like.

Comment: please check again i put my table, sorry for my bad english i can't explain it briefly. thanks for helping me

Comment: Right, so you want to know how many are left?  room qty - SUM(qty of prereservations)?  Would you ideal result table contain room_id, qty left?

Comment: yes thats right, SUM(qty of prereservations) that are in range of those 3 queries, the problem is, if there's too many inputs in database, sometimes the SUM(qty of prereservations) of query1 and the SUM(qty of prereservations) of query2 have same id's thats why i want to use array_merge and array_unique for the id's, so the SUM(qty of prereservations) of query1, query2 and query3 cannot be doubled,tripled or much higher result.

Comment: i like your answer i learned from it, but we ignored the most important the inputs of dates $arrival and $departure. you just get the diff of room qty - SUM(qty of prereservations). here's the scenario, from today 11/02 we assumed the we have a two records in table(prereservations) where arrival = 11/02 | departure = 11/04 qty = 1 and arrival = 11/03 | departure = 11/06 qty = 1, and inputs $arrival = 11/05 | $departure = 11/06. in your given query the answer is room qty = 10 - SUM(qty of prereservations) = 8, but in my query1 room qty = 10 - SUM(qty of prereservations) = 9, bcoz i used between